# Blocked request to a resource of another origin error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, netlify, netlify-function

I am using Netlify Functions in my web application and getting the following error: "Blocked request to a resource of another origin: the "Same Origin Policy" rules do not allow loading remote resources from http://localhost:8888/api/contact". I need help in resolving this issue. Can anyone provide any suggestions or solutions for this problem specifically with Netlify Functions?

When I set proxy in package.json

> "proxy": "http://localhost:8888",

it works but only on development on production it doesnt.How can achive it to work for development and production.

this is my netlify config

```
[build]
  command = "astro build"
  functions = "netlify/functions"
  publish = "dist"
[functions]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[[redirects]]
  from = "/api/*" # simplify all calls to serverless functions
  to = "/.netlify/functions/:splat" # all function calls will go to this path
  status = 200 # ok code
  force = true # ensure to always redirect
```

i have netlify/functions/contact.ts

```
import { createTransport } from "nodemailer";

if (!process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY) {
  throw new Error("Missing SENDINBLUE_API_KEY");
}

if (!process.env.TO_EMAIL) {
  throw new Error("Missing TO_EMAIL");
}

export const handler = async ({ body }) => {
  try {
    let payload;
    try {
      payload = JSON.parse(body);
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Invalid request body" }),
      };
    }
    const { name, email, message } = payload;

    if (!name || !email || !message) {
      return {
        statusCode: 422,
        body: "Missing required fields",
      };
    }

    let transporter = createTransport({
      host: "smtp-relay.sendinblue.com",
      port: 587,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.TO_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
      },
    });

    const date = new Date().toDateString();

    const html = `
        <div> 
           You got email from ${name}! <br><br>
           ${message}
           <br><br>
           Date: ${date}
        </div>
      `;
    const mail = {
      from: email,
      to: process.env.TO_EMAIL,
      subject: `Portfolio Contact from ${name}`,
      html: html,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Email sent" }),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: error.statusCode || 500,
      body: error.message,
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following section to your netlify config file:

```
[[headers]]
  for = "/api/*"
  [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "http://localhost:8888"
```

Comment: still the same error on the productrion